# Вынести кнопку из одного компонента в другой

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Есть страница с роутером в виде:

```
<app>
<toolbar/>
<router-view/>
</app>
```

На компонентах в router-view есть методы `save()`, `add()`, `remove()`.

Хочу на панельке нарисовать кнопки для этих операций. Только кнопки должны появляться, только когда методы реализованы во вьюхе и вызывать их.

Наверное, в компоненте app можно как-то получить методы из компонента внутри router-view и передать их в toolbar. В toolbar эти методы должны вызываться с this указывающим на компонент внутри роутера.

Как такое реализовать не сильно костыльно?

Можно ли передать слот из toolbar в компонент view, чтоб нарисовать кнопки там локально?

Comment: Лучше от обратного пойти:подключать в каждой `view` компонент `toolbar` и там переопределять/задавать слоты либо не использовать их вовсе. А в самом компоненте `toolbar` будут также общие, например, выпадающие меню.

Comment: @РустамГимранов не хочется тулбар засовывать во вью. компонентность страдает